# Showing a view in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, view

I'm developing a plug-in in Eclipse and I want to show a view. I'm using this:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("org.eclipse.ui.articles.MyView");
```

however it's being added on the right not at the set of views where I want it to be displayed.

How can I specify the location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found out how.

This gave me the idea of what I should do: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/viewArticle/ViewArticle2.html in the View Position paragraph under the Step 3 section.

When declaring the perspective, I added a placeholder to contain the view. It is shown in the following code:

```
public void defineLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
String editorArea = layout.getEditorArea();   
IFolderLayout bottom =
            layout.createFolder("bottom", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, (float) 0.75f, editorArea);
bottom.addPlaceholder("org.eclipse.ui.articles.MyView");
}
```

Later on, I use:

`PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("org.eclipse.ui.articles.MyView")`

to show the view and it appears where I had declared in the Perspective and not at the default right-hand side.

Hope it could help someone else.

Thanks and regards,

Krt_Malta

Comment: When declaring the perspective, one could use bottom.addView("org.eclipse.ui.articles.MyView"); to show the view immediately once the perspective is loaded, however I didn't want this. I wanted it to be displayed just when required during runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the help and for posting your own solution; this solved a problem I was having just now.